# Sqlite.swift not working with Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift, xcode7.3, swift2

I was using [Sqlite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) with Xcode 7.2.x. It was working fine.

I have updated Xcode to Xcode 7.3 and problem occurs with Sqlite.swift framework.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'Compression'
module Compression [system] [extern_c] {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module Compression [system] [extern_c] {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:6:8: error: redefinition of module 'Darwin'
module Darwin [system] [extern_c] {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:6:8: note: previously defined here
module Darwin [system] [extern_c] {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:1478:8: error: redefinition of module 'os'
module os [system] [extern_c] {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:1599:8: note: previously defined here
module os [system] [extern_c] {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:1494:8: error: redefinition of module 'libkern'
module libkern [system] [extern_c] {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:1615:8: note: previously defined here
module libkern [system] [extern_c] {
       ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'SQLite'
```

Using version : `pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.9.2'`

I found a closed pool request with the same issue. https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/349

I have tried using following branch :

```
pod 'SQLite.swift',
  git: 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git',
  branch: 'cocoapods-xcode-7-3'
```

But I could not able to solve this problem.

Waiting for genuine solution.

Comment: I'm using their [7.3 branch](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/tree/cocoapods-xcode-7-3) without issues. Same repo, just not the same branch. :)

Comment: @EricD: You should submit this as an answer.

Comment: Why downvotes? !! Many developers facing this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer is unfortunately inaccurate. Both `master` and the latest version, `0.10.1` (released [a couple days ago](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/releases/tag/0.10.1)), are compatible with Xcode 7.3 and CocoaPods 1.0.0 beta 6.

The Xcode upgrade process had some snags this time around, though, and one or more of the following steps were needed for several users after updating CocoaPods and the pod:

- If you haven't already, update to the latest *beta* version of CocoaPods:

  Run `sudo gem update cocoapods --pre` and re-run `pod install`.
- Hold the "option" key and run **Clean Build Folder…** from Xcode's **Product** menu before re-building.
- Delete the "Pods" folder from your project directory and re-run `pod install`.
- If all else fails, delete "Xcode.app" from the "Applications" folder and re-install (a few users had bad Xcode installs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check.

Comment: I have tried this on two different computers and it hasn't worked. I am now trying the last step, reinstalling Xcode, on one of them. Is there something more?

Comment: I got it to work by changing the line in the Podfile to `pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.10.1'` Thanks!

Comment: @FrankConry Did that help? I can't get anything to work and don't really have time to reinstall right now.

Comment: @CodyHarness yes. That worked. Follow the steps above and modify the Podfile as I described and it should work without having to reinstall xcode

Comment: Unfortunately I've already made that change in my podfile and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @CodyHarness Have you tried all the non-Xcode-reinstall steps outlined above? Cleaning your build folder, for one, but beyond that, updating CocoaPods and reinstalling your local pods should be fast enough. Short of that, a non-CocoaPods-based installation method should unblock you. (CocoaPods is unfortunately a brittle solution for SDK lib wrappers like SQLite.swift.)

Comment: @CodyHarness I should also have mentioned that after changing your `Podfile` you should re run `pod install`

Comment: @stephencelis yes, First thing I did this morning was update CocoaPods itself, then updated my pods, then cleaned my build folder. Then I found this post, tried deleting the pods folder and running `pod install`, just to always come back to the error. Now I've completely removed pods from to project, everything, and ran `pod install` to get everything in fresh. Now I get the error (among others) "'SQLite/SQLite-Bridging.h' file not found"

Comment: I did not need to update Cocoapods.  I'm using 1.0.0.beta.5 (6 caused me many problems a few weeks ago with other pods).  All I did was to clean the build folder (keybinding: Option-Shift-Command-K), and re-run pod install.  I did not specify SQLite version in my podfile, but I did point to the github url location using: `pod 'SQLite.swift', git: 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git'`

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. cocoapods beta6 and sqlite.swift 0.10.1 still see CSQlite duplication errors :(

Comment: @SergeyPronin the same for me. xcode 7.3.1 with sqlite.swift 0.10.1. I tried all options, but it still gives me that error.

Answer (score 4):

The "master" branch of the SQLite.swift repository is not compatible with Xcode 7.3.

Fortunately, the author has already made a compatible branch:

> https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/tree/cocoapods-xcode-7-3

This is the one you should use in Xcode 7.3 (I'm using it without any issues).

This is the same repository: it's just a different branch. We can guess it will be merged with "master" as soon as the author sees fit.

Comment: Ok. I will check this one. but can we do it by using pod?

Comment: @AshishKakkad There's no pod for this version yet. But install is simple: drag the SQLite.swift xcodeproject to your project, then add the linked SQLite library in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will check.

Comment: Build successfully. Thanks.

Comment: @EricD That branch was already merged and version bumped (the only reason I haven't deleted it is so that people successfully locked to it don't have issues—I'll probably delete it in a month or so).

Comment: @stephencelis Ok, I see. I previously tried to use your master branch with 7.3 and failed, therefore my answer to Ashish's question. Thank you for these precious informations, I'll try that for my own install.

Comment: @EricD I'm guessing it hadn't been merged at the time you updated :) 0.10.0 was released 4 days ago but still had a lingering issue that affected _some_ CocoaPods users. 0.10.1 should have resolved it! If you're still having problems, please file an issue!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xcode 7.3, and Cocoapods version `1.0.0.beta.5`.  I am **not** using the most recent version of Cocoapods because it caused me many problems a few weeks ago with other pods that I'm using, and I don't want to update it again until I feel that it is more stable.

What worked for me:

1. Clean the build folder (keybinding: `Option-Shift-Command-K`)
2. Delete `Pods/` directory and delete the `Podfile.lock` file **(don't delete `Podfile`!)**
3. Confirm your podfile contains the import syntax that points to the github url using:

`pod 'SQLite.swift', git: 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git'`

1. Save your Podfile edits, if any
2. Run `pod install`